# Как перейти на рабочий стол в git bash?

Tags: git

Я сейчас нахожусь в /c/Users/Данила/, нужно перейти на рабочий стол  на папку, которая на ней, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

От этого пути, каталога пользователя, перейди в каталог `Desktop` так `cd ./Desktop`, а затем уже переходи в нужный каталог, расположенный на рабочем столе.

Answer (score 0):

Можно кликнуть правую кнопку мыши и выбрать Git Bash Here. Находясь в нужной папке или как в вашем случае на рабочем столе.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего, отталкиваясь от домашнего каталога:

```bash
cd ~/Desktop/
```